# Calling map(Arrays::toString) on a Stream produced by Java Stream.of() vs. IntStream vs. Arrays.stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why can't the method `toString` be resolved when I'm using `Arrays.stream()` or `IntStream`:

```
int row[] = ...
Arrays.stream(row)
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But, on the other hand, it can be resolved when I'm using `Stream.of()`:

```
int row[] = ...
Stream.of(row)
       .map(Arrays::toString)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream.of(row)` would return a `Stream<int[]>` whose single element is the `row` array. `Arrays` contains a static method `toString` that accepts an `int[]`, so your second snippet passes compilation.

On the other hand, `Arrays.stream(row)` (as well as `IntStream.of(row)`) returns an `IntStream` whose elements are `int`. There is no `toString` method in `Arrays` class that takes an `int` argument.

You could use `Integer`'s `static` `toString` method instead :

```
Arrays.stream(row)
      .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that you should call `mapToObj` and not `map` when you are mapping a primitive `int` to a reference type.

Comment: @Ervan, it is enough to call `boxed` on  a `IntSteam` to convert a primitive to a wrapper. And we don't really need this conversion to just print individual array elements. `Arrays.stream(row).forEach(System.out::println);` will work as well.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc That's true.